# height issue (overflow) with 3 column layout

Tags: css

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
#app{
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.row{
 display: flex;
 height: 100%;
}
.col-3 {
 width: 20%;
 background: red;
}
.col-6 {
 width: 60%;
 background-color:blue;
}
#large-item{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
   <h2>left column</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
   <h2>middle column</h2>
      <div id="large-item">Large item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
   <h2>right column</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

I create a 3 column layout following the instruction of w3cschools. The problem is if I set html,body height to 100%, the large item in the columns will overflow, which is ugly. How can I make it responsive like automatically add a scrollbar and the background color still fill the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I would suggest you to set the height of `.col-6 > h2` to `30px` and `#large-item` height to `calc(100% - 70px);`. We are subtracting `70px` because `30px` is the height of h2 and `20px` is the margin of h2 (top + bottom = `40px`). So 30px + 40px is `70px` what we need to subtract.</strike>

**Update 1:**
You will need to add parent container for large item to see the scrollbar when it has more content. And set it's height to `calc(100% - 70px);` and set `overflow:auto;`. To see the scrollbar, you can set the height of the large-item to `500px` (for example)..

See the snippet.

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
#app{
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.row{
 display: flex;
 height: 100%;
}
.col-3 {
 width: 20%;
 background: red;
}
.col-6 {
 width: 60%;
 background-color:blue;
}
#large-item-container{
  overflow:auto;
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
}
.col-6 > h2{
  height:30px;
}
#large-item{
  height:500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
   <h2>left column</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
   <h2>middle column</h2>
      <div id="large-item-container">
        <div id="large-item">Large item</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
   <h2>right column</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/rkuf49np/1/

If you want to add scrollbar for whole col-6 then its even easier. You don't need large-item-container.

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/1ytka5rj/1/)

Enjoy! :)

Comment: Can we add a scroll bar for the middle column?

Comment: You mean in the `col-6` ?

Comment: Yes, so that when the item is too large we can scroll down

Comment: Sure, but do you want scollbar on `col-6` or on `large-item` only? So when you scoll largeitem, you will still be able to see middle column h2!

Comment: I have updated the answer for both scenario. Please accept the answer if you feel it fixes your problem. :)

Comment: Thanks! very helpful

Answer (score 0):

you just change the height of the `large item` to 92%.

92% is the closest to the other colums height.

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
#app{
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.row{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}
.col-3 {
    width: 20%;
    background: red;
}
.col-6 {
    width: 60%;
    background-color:blue;
}
#large-item{
  height: 92%;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Why 92%? You should give some explanation for the solution.

Comment: 92% is the closest to the other colums height

Comment: Yea add it to your answer so people can see the explanation of your answer. :)